# Смена фона кнопки, созданной из шаблона

Tags: c#, wpf

Проблема в том, что он не устанавливается:

Определяю шаблон:

```
<Window.Resources>
<Style x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Border BorderBrush="#FF797979" BorderThickness="1" >
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}" Content="Кнопка" Name="my_button"/>
```

При смене фон не изменяется:

```
my_button.Background = Brushes.AliceBlue;
```

Подскажите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решилась привязкой свойства к шаблону.

```
 <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
```

Может кто предложит другие варианты?

Хотя, МСДН пишет: "Единственный способ управлять содержимым шаблона элемента управления, это управлять из того же шаблона."

Comment: Это самый простой и правильный способ из всех.